# $f(\bar{A})= \overline{f(A)}$ when $f_{|A}$ is homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous map between topological spaces, and let $A  \subseteq X$ be such that $f_{|A}: A \to f(A)$ is a homeomorphism.

Is it true then that $f(\bar{A})=\overline{f(A)}$?

"$\subset$" is always true since $f$ is continuous, but is the other one also true in this case?

**Remark.** Although I am interested in if the fact is true in general, I am allowed to suppose that $X$ is Hausdorff, second countable, and even compact.

Comment: In the reals (as both spaces) use the whole space in the domain and an open interval in the codomain.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Very nice. Like $\arctan$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactness is the key, as for non compact spaces the statement is false: consider the arctangent function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

If $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then $\bar{A}$ is compact, so also $f(\bar{A})$ is compact. In particular, $f(\bar{A})$ is closed (assuming also $Y$ is Hausdorff), so $f(\bar{A})\supseteq \overline{f(A)}$.

As you observe, the reverse inclusion follows from continuity.

A counterexample with $Y$ non Hausdorff can be obtained by “doubling” a point in $f(\bar{A})$: the doubled point will belong to $\overline{f(A)}$, but not to $f(\bar{A})$.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!!!